# How do I configure NGINX not to cache empty upstream responses?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Whenever my upstream server sees fishy requests, it responses with an emptiness as part of security and DDoS protection (because they’re not worth a single cycle of my CPUs), and I don’t want it to be cached by NGINX, in which case the cache will be poisoned.

How should I configure NGINX to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I’m trying this. Not sure if this’ll do or not.

```
map $upstream_response_length $upstream_response_emptiness {
    0 1;
    default 0;
}
proxy_no_cache $upstream_response_emptiness;
```

---

## Edit

Thinking of it, an empty response does not have a status code.

I guess specifying status codes of responses to cache with `proxy_cache_valid` is sufficient?